# Is there a way to programmatically open VSCode and then open the built-in terminal in VSCode on Mac?

Tags: mac, applescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to automate the process of opening VSCode and then opening its built-in terminal. I know I can open VSCode easily, but I don't know how I can communicate with VSCode once it is opened. Is there some sort of way to connect to it? I could even somehow mimic typing the keyboard shortcut to open the terminal `(control + backtick)`.

Thanks!

Comment: [Related question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70785576/can-i-programmatically-control-script-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2):

you could add a startup script by first changing directory to project folder first `cd my/project/folder`and then using `code .` to open vscode.

i believe the in-built terminal opens itself automatically.